# Javascript / PHP check the data onLeave of Inputfield and save it for "after click button"

Tags: php, css

Hello community Stackoverflow,

i recently begun again to make some experiments with web developing and I would appreciate it, if you could help me with the following issue:

I'm trying to save the string of each input in the following pictured form in a database, after the mouse cursor had left the textBox (OnLeave), this string will be called from the database, after the user clicked on the button "save". I need to check this string before the data being saved after clicking on "save"

Exemple:

step 1: a user types his Name = 'Stackoverflower' in the inputfield and then moves the mouse cursor outside the the inputfiel;

step 2: by leaving the inputfiel occurs the following event, in the background:
a php code will save that input (the name: 'Stackoverflower') in the database;

step 3: after the user clicked on the button "save", a php code will call that string 'Stackoverflower';

That is a solution, but I don't want to save any data in the database unless the user clicks "save". So how can I save that input temporarily (not in the database - maybe in a hidden dom element ? Or do you maybe have a better idea?).

I'll appreciate your interaction

Friendly regards
Reda

[image: A form]

Comment: PHP only executes on page load, to do this, you will need to use Ajax to execute the save PHP script.

Comment: Thanks for replaying. True, with Ajax. I need a solution to store that string temporarily. I need to check that string after the user clicked on the save-button. Is there a solution to keep that string stored somewhere, may be in a hidden paragraph-element or a maybe is there a smarter solution, which is efficient and 
resource-saving?

Comment: I'll make it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP only executes on page load, to do this, you will need to use Ajax to execute the save PHP script.

To store the value, you can use a variable.

```js
let fname; // declare the fname value
let lname; // declare the lname value
let bday; // declare the bday value

function mouseLeft() {
  fname = document.getElementById('fname').value; // store the first name value
  lname = document.getElementById('lname').value; // store the last name value
  bday = document.getElementById('bday').value; // store the birthday value
  
  //optional:
  document.getElementById('storedvalues').innerText = "fname=" + fname + ", lname=" + lname + ", bday=" + bday;  
  
  // your ajax script goes here with fname, lname and bday being the values of their respective inputs
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body onmouseleave="mouseLeft();"> <!-- function that executes on mouse leave -->
    <form> <!-- your form goes here, just add the ids to the inputs -->
      <label for="fname">First name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="fname">
      <br>
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="lname">
      <br>
      <label for="bday">Birthday:</label>
      <input type="date" id="bday">
    </form>
    
    <!-- optional, just for debug -->
    <p>stored values: <span id="storedvalues">fname=, lname=, bday=</span></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can [learn about variables here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables).

---

Here's an example GET request with AJAX, which you can adapt to fit your code:

```
var objXMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
objXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(objXMLHttpRequest.readyState === 4) {
    if(objXMLHttpRequest.status === 200) {
          alert(objXMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    } else {
          alert('Error Code: ' +  objXMLHttpRequest.status);
          alert('Error Message: ' + objXMLHttpRequest.statusText);
    }
  }
}
objXMLHttpRequest.open('GET', 'request_ajax_data.php');
objXMLHttpRequest.send();
```

You can learn how to use and [adapt this code here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-ajax-in-php-and-jquery--cms-32494).

---

You could also programmatically execute a form that opens in a new tab instead of using AJAX, which is the easier route in my opinion.

```js
// use vars, put in function under variables being  set

document.getElementById('fnamef2input').value = fname;
document.getElementById('lnamef2input').value = lname;
document.getElementById('bdayf2input').value = bday;

// submit form, put in function:

document.getElementById('mySecondForm').submit();
```

```html
<form action="..." method="GET" id="mySecondForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="fname" id="fnamef2input">
  <input type="hidden" name="lname" id="lnamef2input">
  <input type="hidden" name="bday" id="bdayf2input">
</form>
```

Comment: I like your last post. I think the first solution is the suitable one in my case. so, I store the value in a hidden p/ span element, which will later be called and processed, after the user clicked "save". I like that instance of Ajax, XMLHttpRequest. The third solution is also useful in some cases. Beautiful codes, thank you for this enriching post *thumbsup

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this as accepted (the ✔ button under the upvote on the answer) so this post can help others!